# Button combination for bypassing Xbox 360 disc autoplay

Tags: xbox-360

Is there anything similar to holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> in Windows for temporary disabling the inserted disc autoplay?

Comment: I know it's an option you can turn off, but a button combo to not autoplay as you insert a disc? Good question.

Comment: @Matt Yeah I know about disabling it completely, sometimes I just want to insert a disc without playing it right away.

Comment: I think if you use the dashboard icon to close the tray after putting the new disc in (instead of closing it manually) then it skips autoplay. Not 100% sure though (can't test currently), and this obviously couldn't be used to skip autoplay when first booting the console up.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is **no way** similar to holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> in Windows to temporarily disable autoplay on Xbox 360.

Answer (score -3):

Xbox guide on controller(silver button)>system settings>console settings>auto-play disabled